# Sorting using radix sort

Tags: java, radix-sort

I was reading `radix sort` from [this site](http://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/radix-sort/tutorial/) I am confused in the 3rd `for loop`:

```
for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    output[freq[(arr[i] / place) % range] - 1] = arr[i];
    freq[(arr[i] / place) % range]--;
}
```

Why did they start it from the end as when I tried to start it from 0, it gives me the wrong answer? Any explanation or solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `freq` contains the cumulative number of elements in each position in the range. That is, for a range of i=0-9, `freq[i]` contains the number of digits that are placed on positions `0, ..., i`.

The algorithm uses `freq` to keep track of how many items it needs to draw from initial array to the output array for each position.

Assuming 10,21,17,34,44,11,654,123 as input, running count-sort for first insignificant digit:

```
0: 10
1: 21 11
2:
3: 123
4: 34 44 654
5:
6:
7: 17
8:
9:
```

`freq` would be as:

```
0: 1
1: 3
2: 3
3: 4
4: 7
5: 7
6: 7
7: 8
8: 8
9: 8
```

So, the array becomes 10,21,11,123,34,44,654,17.

You need to loop backwards to keep *the original order of numbers with the same digit*, because how the `freq` is built. Suppose you want to place 34 to its right place on the output. According to the `freq` array, if loop forward, you would place it on the 7th position which is incorrect. If you loop backwards, you have already placed 654 and 44 before reaching 34, so `freq[4]=5` by then which is the correct place.

Comment: What if I want to run the loop from index 1 to the size of the array?

Comment: That is what I meant by "looping forward". You cannot preserve the "original order" of the bucket by looping forward. You can only do that by looping "backwards".